# How to Change A Number In An Array that was converted from a CSV File- Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I am a beginner python programmer. My task was to import a csv file and do the following:

1. Convert the file into an array
2. Being able to change values in the array
3. Assign the data to a variable

The following is the code I have so far and I really need some help as soon as possible.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
f = open("Test.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    print(np.array(row))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `append()` each line to `array`. Example:

```
myArray = []
for row in csv_f:
    myArray.append(row)
```

`Append` will add row at the end of the array. In the end, you will get array looking like this: `[row1, row2, row3, ...]`. After that you can use `indexing` for deleting/changing values. Example:

```
myArray[0] = "banana"
```

Right now, your array will look like: `["banana", row2, row3"]`. Note, that indexing always starts from 0 (it's first element). Trying to call index that does not exists will result in `IndexError`. Example:

```
print(myArray[5])
```

Will result in following message: `IndexError: list index out of range`. You can use `try....except` statements to deal with this error. Example:

```
try:
    myArray[5]
except IndexError:
    print("Index out of range!")
```

Now instead of `IndexError` program will print message and most important - it will keep going, instead of exiting.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to assign the data to a variable? Before you answered, I believe I actually answered my own question so I managed to change values in the array and I was able to print out specific columns. But would it be possible (like I said above) if I could assign the data to a variable? So that if I wanted the first column of the array, I could just type in: Variable[1]  ?

Comment: If my answer was correct, please upvote it ;) I don't fully understand your question. Do you want to be able to assign specific row to a variable? just type: `myVariableName = myArray[1]`.

Comment: I did but I don't have enough "reputation" to make it public. To rephrase my question differently, would it be possible to assign the data to a variable? For instance, myVariableName[1] would print out the 2nd column?

Comment: It depends of data type, but generally - yes.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?